# Android OnClick Behaviour: Image disappearing

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener, android-gridview

I am creating an application that the user can move an image from each spot in a GridLayout/LinearLayout.

For example:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Grid"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="50dp"
                  android:layout_height="50dp"
                  android:id="@+id/AnswerOne"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_row="0"
                  android:layout_column="0"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageOne"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="50dp"
                  android:layout_height="50dp"
                  android:id="@+id/AnswerTwo"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_row="0"
                  android:layout_column="1"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageTwo"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I have onClickListeners like this:

```
Images[0].setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
    @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            clipDataImage = GameBoardOnDragListenerSwitchMethod(event, v, 0);
            return clipDataImage ;
        }
    });

Images[1].setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
    @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            clipDataImage = GameBoardOnDragListenerSwitchMethod(event, v, 1);
            return clipDataImage ;
        }
    });
```

Method Used in onDrag:

```
public boolean GameBoardOnDragListenerSwitchMethod(DragEvent myDrag, View myV, int dragListenerValue){

    switch (myDrag.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            if (myDrag.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                myV.invalidate();
                return true;
            }
            return true;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            gameImages[dragListenerValue].setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            gameImages[dragListenerValue].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            return true;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:

            return true;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            gameImages[dragListenerValue].setBackgroundColor(0);
            gameImages[dragListenerValue].setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

            return true;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            DragEvent myEvent = myDrag;
            getGameImages(myEvent, dragListenerValue);

            return true;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

            return true;

        // An unknown action type was received.
        default:
            Log.e("DragDrop Example", "Unknown action type received by OnDragListener.");
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

For this application the user can click an image and move it to a different imageView inside the linearlayout to change the location. The problem occurs when trying to move the image back. Whenever the image moves back to a spot that the image was already at it will just disappear.

Example:

[image]

I have been looking into this and cannot figure out why when an Image is moved back to a spot that already had an image at some point why it disappears. I thought perhaps it had something to do with returning true or false for the OnClick Listener but my implementation did not seem to make a difference.